# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException' - unrecognized selector

Tags: objective-c, unrecognized-selector

***I'm trying to make a simple notes app. When I run the project, in the debug area, it says***;

```
[1752:19d03] -[TableViewController createEditableCopyOfDatabasteIfNeeded]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa147d20

[1752:19d03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TableViewController createEditableCopyOfDatabasteIfNeeded]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa147d20'
```

**And my code, includes *createEditableCopyOfDatabasteIfNeeded*, is** ;

```
- (void)createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded {

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *documentDirectory = [self applicationDocumentsDirectory];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"NotesList.plist"];

    BOOL dbexits = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
    if (!dbexits) {

        NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"NotesList.plist"];

        NSError *error;
        BOOL success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
        if (!success) {
            NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Where is the problem here ?**
***It might be an easy one but I'm new to Xcode.***
*Thanks for help*

Comment: First of your issue is `unrecognized selector` this is because you are trying to call a method called `createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded` on a `UITableView` and it doesn't know what it is. Where do you call `createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded`? Second you don't need to show `main.m` this is where it will end exit if you don't catch the exception it's known as an `Uncaught Exception` and will kill your app. Do as `Epatel` answer says to actual break on the exception itself.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you also add a breakpoint in Xcode for all Exceptions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are calling methods `createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded` that is not defined in class `TableViewController`. You can got to breakpoints tab and add new breakpoint (plus button) and select a checkamrk to hold on all exceptions or something like that. That should help you track where your app is crashing.

What class is implementing `createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded` method?

Comment: 1) just do what @epatel suggested in his image, add a "All Exceptions" break point and (hopefully) this will enable you to see where real exception happens (main is just a place where your app breaks)
2) Past your whole TableViewController.m file so we can see it
3) Didi you declare createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded in your TableViewController.h header?

Answer (score 0):

The error does give you all of the information you need in this case. You have the function defined, but it's not in the TableViewController class. You should edit your code to call it in the class where it does exist.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've defined the function as -(void) you should call it through an instance of `TableViewController` and not in the "static" way `[TableViewController createEditableCopyOfDatabasteIfNeeded]`